# How to export all collections in database, with URI?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How can I export all my data in MongoDB, with a remote connection? I have my URI and haven't been able to find anything online using that.

```
mongoexport --uri <URI> -f <output_file>
```

This command works when I specify a collection, but I'm not sure how to export all collections using this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongoexport is used to export a collection of a specific db in JSON or CSV format.

You can not export all collections using mongoexport in a single command, you need to make individual request for each collection.

But if you want to take a backup of mongo and want to restore it on another node, then, you must use mongodump command.

As stated in MongoDB documentation,

```
WARNING

Avoid using mongoimport and mongoexport for full instance production backups.
They do not reliably preserve all rich BSON data types, because JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported by BSON.
Use mongodump and mongorestore as described in MongoDB Backup Methods for this kind of functionality.
```

As already suggested, you can instead design a script, which will perform all the steps in order and will provide you with the desired results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For export all the collections you should user the mongdump command.
Here how I use on my database:

```
mongodump -d<databaseName> --gzip --archive=<nomeArquivo.gz>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this export into BSON? Is there a way to get JSON instead?

Comment: That's true! Another option would be you create a script to call a mongoexport for all collections in the database.
You can use the command <pre>db.getCollectionNames()<code> and then iterate each collection and use the mongoexport.

Comment: @EduardoHitek Have you written the script to export all the collections? If so, can you share it with me?

Comment: Not sure why this answer has been downvoted. According to the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--collection) it **is** possible to use `mongodump --db=dataBase` in this manner to create a dump of all data in the database `dataBase`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer since the edit queue is full and as a result doesn't allow me to edit an existing answer.

In more recent MongoDB versions, it's possible to create a data dump of all collections in a database using the command `mongodump`.

```bash
mongodump -d=database1
```

To create a dump of only `collection1` in `database1`:

```bash
mongodump -d=database1 -c=collection1
```

Check out the documentation for [details](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--collection) and some corresponding [examples](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#examples).